# Java, converting epoch to milliseconds

Tags: java, javascript, time, epoch, integer-overflow

My flot graph is not displaying any lines, problem multiplying epoch by 1000 using Integer in Java?
This is my raw data, stored in a `.txt` file

```
epoch,value
1383229104,55559
1383229121,55559
1383229787,55565
```

which is parsed by a Servlet and stored inside:

```
Vector<Integer> points = new Vector<Integer>();
```

e.g

```
points.add(Integer.parseInt(strLine.split(",")[0]) * 1000);
points.add(Integer.parseInt(strLine.split(",")[1]));
```

There are multiple files, each one containing a separate series (line) to be plotted on graph.
For each `Vector<Integer> points` object, they are added to ..

```
Vector<Dataset> datasets = new Vector<Dataset>();
```

Dataset has following definition:

```
public class Dataset {

    private String name;
    private Vector<Vector<Integer>> points;
```

Once all the files have been parsed and added to `Vector<Dataset> datasets`, this object is sent client side using `response.getWriter().write(new Gson().toJson(datasets));`
And 'graphed' using

```
var datasets = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

    var plotarea = $("#placeholder");
    $.plot(plotarea, [datasets[0].points, datasets[1].points, datasets[2].points, datasets[3].points, datasets[4].points], {
        xaxis: {
            mode: "time",
            min: (new Date(2012, 0, 1)).getTime(),
            max: (new Date(2015, 0, 1)).getTime()
        }
    });
```

**Update:** -------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Debugging output within javascript.
There are 5 files being loaded into `Vector<Dataset> datasets = new Vector<Dataset>();`

```
alert(datasets) .. [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
console.log(datasets) .. [object Array]
```

I can access values using:

```
alert(datasets[0].points[0][0]);
alert(datasets[0].points[0][1]);
```

Output will be two alert dialogs, one containing `249634688`, the second `55559`
**Note:** `1383229104 * 1000` should not be `249634688`

Comment: Can you show us the output of `console.log(datasets)`?

Comment: updated description with output from `console.log(datasets)` and `alert(datasets)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `private Vector<Vector<Integer>> points;` to `private Vector<Vector<Long>> points;`
Caused expected result i.e `1383229104000`

Comment: You can see from question that `alert(datasets[0].points[0][0]);` output `249634688` because epoch was multipled by 1000 and stored inside an `Integer` object which can not handle such large values.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using Long, not Integer. Clearly this is an overflow problem.